# Solution of class design issue of generic of restricted type

Tags: c#, generics

I am developing a statistics library in .net. I have developed a `Set<T>` data structure. Now, I want to derive a data structure named `DescriptiveStatisticalSet<T>`, and I want this set to be able to operate only on integer and double types.

**Problem:**

> I want to implement a generic type that is able to work with integer
> and double data types only.
>
> Say, I have the following interfaces and classes:
>
> ```
> public interface IIntegerDataType  
> {
>     int Data { get; set; }
>     int Add(int other);
> }
>
> public interface IDoubleDataType  
> {
>     double Data { get; set; }
>     double Add(double other);
> }
> public class IntegerDataType : IIntegerDataType
> {
>     public int Data { get; set; }
>
>     public int Add(int other)
>     {
>         return Data + other;
>     }
> }
> public class DoubleDataType : IDoubleDataType
> {
>     public double Data { get; set; }
>
>     public double Add(double other)
>     {
>         return Data + other;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Is it possible to create a generic type `DataType<T>` so that both
> (and only) `IntegerDataType` and `DoubleDataType` could be accessed
> through that generic type?

**Solution:**

I have devised [the following solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qJGsAK):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataTypeNamespace
{
    public interface IDataType
    {
        object Add(object other); 
        void SetVal(object other);
    }
    public interface IDataType<T> where T : IDataType, new()
    {
        T Add(T other);
    }
    class IntegerDataType : IDataType
    {
        public int Data { get; set; }

        public object Add(object other)
        {
            int o = ((IntegerDataType)other).Data;
            return Data + o;
        }
        public void SetVal(object other)
        {
            Data = (int)other;
        }
    }

    class DoubleDataType : IDataType
    {
        public double Data { get; set; }

        public object Add(object other)
        {
            double o = ((DoubleDataType)other).Data;
            return Data + o;
        }

        public void SetVal(object other)
        {
            Data = (double)other;
        }
    }

    public class DataType<T> : IDataType<T> where T : IDataType, new()//https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint
    {
        IDataType _item;
        public DataType(IDataType item)
        {
            _item = item;
        }

        public T Add(T other)
        {
            object o = _item.Add(other);

            T t = new T();

            t.SetVal(o);

            return t;
        }
    }

    public class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //IntegerDataType item1 = new IntegerDataType();
            //item1.Data = 10;

            //IntegerDataType item2 = new IntegerDataType();
            //item2.Data = 20;

            //DataType<IntegerDataType> l1 = new DataType<IntegerDataType>(item1);
            //IntegerDataType sum1 = l1.Add(item2);

            DoubleDataType item3 = new DoubleDataType();
            item3.Data = 10.5;

            DoubleDataType item4 = new DoubleDataType();
            item4.Data = 20.5;

            DataType<DoubleDataType> l2 = new DataType<DoubleDataType>(item3);
            DoubleDataType sum2 = l2.Add(item4);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone review this? Or, maybe help me to improve?

Comment: I like your namespace naming :D `IDataTypeeeeeeeeeee`

Comment: This boxing and boxing (i.e.: `object other`) introduces a lot of unnecessary memory pressure (allocating a value type on a heap). Generics would be a much more preferable approach.

Comment: Links rot. Don't point to another site for explanation of your problem, include the relevant text here.

Comment: @BCdotWEB I think it's been fixed.

Comment: I'm not sure that the effort you're going through is worth any benefit you get from it. Why would any implicitly convertable type be unacceptable? If you can write code that generically handles both ints and doubles, why could it then not handle other numeric types? Maybe try to answer the [5 whys](https://www.isixsigma.com/tools-templates/cause-effect/determine-root-cause-5-whys) on why you want/need this? I.e. why do you need this? [in response to that answer] Why is that? [and repeat].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I think you're trying to solve an XY-problem. If I understand the term "`DescriptiveStatisticalSet`", you want to provide a data set class, that exposes some  significant statistical properties and therefore the generic type parameter of the set must be a numeric type of some kind (int, double, ??). To fix that, you try to develop a certain `int` and `double` data type, that you can constraint the `DescriptiveStatisticalSet<T>`'s type parameter with. I think you'll get tired of that design rather quickly, because you'll have to convert to/from this "intermediate" type constantly, whenever you'll want to use the set.

I think I would go in another direction by only allow the creation of `DescriptiveStatisticalSet<T>` for certain data types, which can be done in the following way:

```
  // For this illustration, I've just implemented the Set<T> as a generic list sub class. Yours is surely more sophisticated.
  public class Set<T> : List<T>
  {
    public Set()
    {

    }

    public Set(IEnumerable<T> data) : base(data)
    {

    }
  }


  public abstract class DescriptiveStatisticalSet<T> : Set<T>
  {
    protected DescriptiveStatisticalSet(IEnumerable<T> data) : base(data)
    {

    }

    public virtual T Average => default;
    public virtual T Median => default;
    public virtual T StdDev => default;
    // TODO public other key values...
  }

  public static class DescriptiveStatisticalSet
  {
    private class IntDescriptiveStatisticalSet : DescriptiveStatisticalSet<int>
    {
      public IntDescriptiveStatisticalSet(IEnumerable<int> data) : base(data)
      {

      }

      public override int Median
      {
        get
        {
          var ordered = this.OrderBy(v => v).ToArray();
          if (Count % 2 == 0) return (ordered[Count / 2] + ordered[Count / 2 + 1]) / 2;
          return ordered[Count / 2];
        }
      }
    }

    private class DoubleDescriptiveStatisticalSet : DescriptiveStatisticalSet<double>
    {
      public DoubleDescriptiveStatisticalSet(IEnumerable<double> data) : base(data)
      {

      }

      public override double Median
      {
        get
        {
          var ordered = this.OrderBy(v => v).ToArray();
          if (Count % 2 == 0) return (ordered[Count / 2] + ordered[Count / 2 + 1]) / 2.0;
          return ordered[Count / 2];
        }
      }

    }

    public static DescriptiveStatisticalSet<int> Create(IEnumerable<int> data)
    {
      return new IntDescriptiveStatisticalSet(data);
    }

    public static DescriptiveStatisticalSet<double> Create(IEnumerable<double> data)
    {
      return new DoubleDescriptiveStatisticalSet(data);
    }

  }
```

---

Used as:

```
  var doubleStatSet = DescriptiveStatisticalSet.Create(new[] { 1.2, 3.4, 5.6 });
  Console.WriteLine(doubleStatSet.GetType().Name);
  Console.WriteLine(doubleStatSet.Median);
  var intStatSet = DescriptiveStatisticalSet.Create(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
  Console.WriteLine(intStatSet.GetType().Name);
  Console.WriteLine(intStatSet.Median);

  var decimalStatSet = DescriptiveStatisticalSet.Create(new[] { 1.2m, 3.4m, 5.6m }); // ERROR wont compile
```

---

A simpler construct that builds on the same principles is to always operate on `double` in `DescriptiveStatisticalSet` and then only provide two constructors: one that takes a `double` data set and another taking an `int` data set:

```
  public class DescriptiveStatisticalSet : Set<double>
  {
    public DescriptiveStatisticalSet(IEnumerable<double> data) : base(data)
    {
    }

    public DescriptiveStatisticalSet(IEnumerable<int> data) : this(data.Cast<double>())
    {

    }

    public double Average => ((IEnumerable<double>)this).Average();
    public double Median => default;
    public double StdDev => default;
    // TODO public other key values...

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As has been said in the comments, it's unclear why you feel you need this behaviour to restrict the types used.  There's an interesting discussion around constraining types [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34186/592182), which includes a link to example code.

So, there's a couple of questions.  Why do you need to restrict it to `double` / `integer` types?  Is it really that you want to do is restrict it to types that support certain operations?  What is the actual downside to using it for `Decimal` / `float`?

You've presented an example of `IDataType`, however suggested that really your goal is to put these items into a set.  So this begs the question, are you planning on creating `DescriptiveStatisticalSet<IntegerDataType>` or `DescriptiveStatisticalSet<IDataType>`?  If it's `IntegerDataType`, what are you gaining over `Int32` for example?  If it's `IDataType`, then are you expecting to have both `IntegerDataType`  and `DoubleDataType` both present in the same set?  If so, what are you planning on doing if an Integer has the same value as a Double?  Do you keep both because they are different types, or keep whichever one was there first, or keep the Double because it's more flexible, or the Integer because it's faster?

Looking at your actual code, there's some aspects which are worth mentioning.

> ```
> object Add(object other);
> ```

If we look at `IntegerDataType`, this method takes in an other of type `IntegerDataType`, but returns an `int`.  This it not at all obvious from the method signature.  You are working around this to an extent in your `DataType` class, which does some recasting by creating a new instance of the returned object, however this seems unnecessarily complex.  Particularly since the implementation of `Add` relies on casting `other` to the correct type.  Calling `Add` with a `DoubleDataType` for example throws a cast exception.

> ```
> public int Data { get; set; }
> ```

Both your `Integer` and `Double` data types declare a `Data` property that has both public getter and setter.  Since you're implementing an interface to `setVal`, does it really make sense to declare this public setter?  It feels like it would be better for the `set` to be private, in order to encourage the client to use the interface method, in case you decide you need to do additional checking in the future.

Your `DataType` class seems to exist purely to create a new item from the `object` version of `Add`.  This seems to add unnecessary complexity over just having the initial `Add` return the correct datatype.  So, it's a bit unclear to me what advantage your current approach has over simply doing this:

```
public interface IOtherDataType<T>
{
    T Data { get;}

    IOtherDataType<T> Add(IOtherDataType<T> other);
    void SetVal(T other);
}

public class IntType : IOtherDataType<int>
{
    public IntType(int data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public int Data { get; private set; }

    public IOtherDataType<int> Add(IOtherDataType<int> other)
    {
        return new IntType(Data + other.Data);
    }

    public void SetVal(int other)
    {
        Data = other;
    }
}
```

Which can be used in a similar way...

```
IntType five = new IntType(5);
IOtherDataType<int> eleven = five.Add(new IntType(6));
```